# Change scss variable value based on button click

Tags: sass, angular7

I am creating an angular 7 application which has a main welcome screen with 3 buttons(lets say redirecting to Mens, Womens,kids homepage). i have single homepage component and each page has same layout. but their theme color is different. how can i apply 3 different colors on a single component based on some angular logic. i need pure scss or angular based answers only. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using [Css Variables](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp)
I found some example `code` for that [here](https://codepen.io/wesbos/pen/adQjoY)

Comment: Nice solution. but i am using SCSS in angular 7. i need workaround for that. thanks

Comment: SCSS doesn't exclude using css-variables, Sass, Less and Stylus are just pre-processors. Pure CSS code is valid SCSS. So no workaround is needed.

Comment: Thansk for help :)